# Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi problem after Suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, suspend

I have this problem, after my laptop wakes up from suspend, my wifi connection is treated and shown as wired.
Internet still works but no wifi connection is detected just a wired one.
Running `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service` seems to work, but only the after the first suspend.
If the laptop goes to sleep once more the only solution is a reboot.
I am using the default ubuntu network manager.

lshw:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: c4
   serial: 00:c2:c6:85:45:2b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:35 memory:f7800000-f7801fff
```

[image: menu with wifi not working]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no difference in lshw before and after the wifi stop working what name is changing?

Comment: Check `dmesg | grep wlan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd as it sounds, the solution that worked for me was disabling/purging ModemManager. I had very similar symptoms as you, but now my system resumes Wifi like a charm.

Comment: After doing this there where no immediate changes, but now after like a week it's working perfectly. I do not know if this was the solution or maybe an update fixed it but anyway thanks!